# How do I use $inject when passing a function into an Angular .factory method?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My original code looked like this (see below). Note the $inject statement.

```
 module app.common {
    interface IProductResource
        extends ng.resource.IResource<app.domain.IProduct> {

    }
    export class ResourceFactory {

        static $inject =["$resource"];
        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        }

        public getProductResource() : ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource> {
            return this.$resource("/api/products/:productId");
        }
    }

    factory.$inject = ["$resource"];
    function factory($resource) : ResourceFactory {
        return new ResourceFactory($resource);
    }

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("resourceFactory",
                ["$resource",
                 factory]);
}
```

My new code leverages the lambda syntax and looks like this (see below). How do I handle the minification issues in this case?

```
 module app.common {
    interface IProductResource
        extends ng.resource.IResource<app.domain.IProduct> {

    }

    export class ResourceFactory {

        static $inject =["$resource"];
        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        }

        public getProductResource() : ng.resource.IResourceClass<IProductResource> {
            return this.$resource("/api/products/:productId");
        }
    }

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("resourceFactory",
                ["$resource",
                 ($resource)=>new ResourceFactory($resource)]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest you should do:

```
 angular
        .module("common.services")
        .service("resourceFactory",ResourceFactory);
```

Because of the use of `static $inject` and `service` it will just work.

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM